# Javascript show under clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have car names list and when user click it i want show model list under its row.But now when i click it split rows.How can i do that ?

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dS2vA/3/

Page First Load
[image: Page]

When i click one of them
[image: Onclick]

I want make like that
[image: I want like this]

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="//otobilge.com/Images/Resimler/thumb/Mazda-2-HB-3K-2008-2010-0.jpg" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" onclick="ShowModels('model_290')" />
            <p>2 Serisi</p>
        </div>
        <div id="model_290" class="modellerList">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span> 2 Hatchback 3 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2010-</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2008-2010</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 2 Hatchback 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2010-</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2007-2010</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 2 MPV 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2006-2008</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2003-2006</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="//otobilge.com/Images/Resimler/thumb/Mazda-6-Sedan-4K-2002-2005-0.jpg" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" onclick="ShowModels('model_291')" />
            <p>6 Serisi</p>
        </div>
        <div id="model_291" class="modellerList">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span> 6 Sedan 4 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2013-</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2010-2012</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2007-2010</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2005-2007</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2002-2005</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 6 SportBreak  Station Wagon 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2012-</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2010-2012</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2008-2010</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2005-2007</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2002-2005</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 6 Hatchback 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2010-2012</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2008-2010</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 6 Sport Hatchback 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2005-2007</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2002-2005</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="//otobilge.com/Images/Resimler/thumb/Mazda-3-HB-5K-2003-2006-0.jpg" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" onclick="ShowModels('model_292')" />
            <p>3 Serisi</p>
        </div>
        <div id="model_292" class="modellerList">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span> 3 Hatchback 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2014 - </a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2011-2013</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2009-2011</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2006-2009</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2003-2006</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 3 Sedan 4 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2014 -</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2011-2013</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2009-2011</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2006-2009</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2003-2006</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img                <img src="//otobilge.com/Images/Resimler/thumb/resimyok.jpg" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" onclick="ShowModels('model_293')" />
                <p>5 Serisi</p>        </div>
        <div id="model_293" class="modellerList">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span> 5 MPV 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2010-</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2010 - </a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2008-2010</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2005-2008</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2005 - 2010</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="//otobilge.com/Images/Resimler/thumb/Mazda-RX-8-Coupe-4K-2003-2008-0.jpg" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" onclick="ShowModels('model_294')" />
            <p>RX-8</p>
        </div>
        <div id="model_294" class="modellerList">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span> RX-8 Coupe 4 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2003-2008</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="//otobilge.com/Images/Resimler/thumb/Mazda-626-HB-5K-1991-1995-0.jpg" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" onclick="ShowModels('model_295')" />
            <p>626</p>
        </div>
        <div id="model_295" class="modellerList">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span> 626 Hatchback 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1999-2002</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1997-1999</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1995-1998</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1991-1995</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="//otobilge.com/Images/Resimler/thumb/Mazda-323-Sedan-4K-1991-1995-0.jpg" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" onclick="ShowModels('model_296')" />
            <p>323</p>
        </div>
        <div id="model_296" class="modellerList">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span> 323 Sedan 4 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2001-2003</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1998-2001</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1997-1998</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1994-1997</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1991-1995</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 323 FastBreak Hatchback 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2001-2003</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1998-2001</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 323 P Hatchback 3 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1998-2001</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1997-1998</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1994-1997</a></span>
                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1991-1995</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 323 Coupe 3 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1997-1998</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li>
                                    <span> 323 Estate  Station Wagon 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 1990-1994</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="//otobilge.com/Images/Resimler/thumb/mazda-cx-5-1[1].png" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive" onclick="ShowModels('model_361')" />
            <p>CX-5</p>
        </div>
        <div id="model_361" class="modellerList">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span> CX-5 5 Kapı</span>

                                        <span><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"> 2012 -</a></span>

                                </li>
                                <hr />

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make special container for description at the end of each row and copy it there on click.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/vva4pwxq/**
 *Be aware that I modified your HTML*

```
$(".row").append('<div class="col-md-12 info"></div>');

$("img").on("click", function(){
    $(".info").html("");
    $(this).closest(".row").find(".info").html($(this).siblings(".modellerList").html());
});
```